# How to get max allowed filesize in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, filesize

Does anyone know how to (natively) get the max allowed file size for a given drive/folder/directory? As in for Fat16 it is ~2gb, Fat32 it was 4gb as far as I remember and for the newer NTFS versions it is something way beyond that.. let alone Mono and the underlying OSes.

Is there anything I can read out / retrieve that might give me a hint on that? Basically I  -know- may app will produce bigger, single files than 2gb and I want to check for that when the user sets the corresponding output path(s)...

Cheers & thanks,
-J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the ideal solution, but I will suggest the following anyway:

```
// Returns the maximum file size in bytes on the filesystem type of the specified drive.
long GetMaximumFileSize(string drive)
{
    var driveInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(drive)

    switch(driveInfo.DriveFormat)
    {
        case "FAT16":
            return 1000; // replace with actual limit
        case "FAT32":
            return 1000; // replace with actual limit
        case "NTFS":
            return 1000; // replace with actual limit
    }
}

// Examples:
var maxFileSize1 = GetMaximumFileSize("C"); // for the C drive
var maxFileSize2 = GetMaximumFileSize(absolutePath.Substring(0, 1)); // for whichever drive the given absolute path refers to
```

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) page on Wikipedia contains a pretty comprehensive list of the maximum file sizes for various filesystems. Depending on the number of filesystems for which you want to check in the `GetMaximumFileSize` function, you may want to use a Dictionary object or even a simple data file rather than a switch statement.

Now, you *may* be retrieve the maximum file size directly using WMI or perhaps even the Windows API, but these solutions will of course only be compatible with Windows (i.e. no luck with Mono/Linux). However, I would consider this a reasonably nice purely managed solution, despite the use of a lookup table, and has the bonus of working reliably on all OSs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about using System.Info.DriveInfo.DriveFormat to retrieve the drive's file system (NTFS, FAT, ect.)? That ought to give you at least some idea of the supported file sizes.